# How to use any React Native module in expo-dev-client?

Tags: react-native, module, expo

https://docs.expo.dev/clients/getting-started/#customizing-your-runtime gave 1 example of how to include the non-Expo module `@react-native-voice/voice` into an Expo project, but if I try to include another non-Expo module such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info , then I ran `expo run:android` it errors with

> Package "react-native-device-info" does not contain a valid config
> plugin. Learn more:
> https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin

. I am expecting some magic way to include non-Expo React Native modules into an Expo project using Custom Development Clients (https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8), is my expectation wrong? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add every react native module to `"plugins"` field in your `app.config`. Most modules have auto linking enabled. Config plugins are just plugins which auto performs extra setup steps. You will get it working without extra configs.

`react-native-device-info` does not have a `app.plugin.js` in repo, which means it does not provide a config plugin. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Does this mean you have to write your own plugin to link it?

Comment: @RexOmiv Expo can handle auto linking. You need to write a config plugin if the module requires extra setups such as modifying some files.